# How to use private docker registry instead of docker hub?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

We need to pull all our base images form a private docker registry. Is pulling the image from
 docker hub and pushing it to the private registry the only option to achieve the above requirement.

Also how to pass credentials of my private registry and tell my Dockerfile to pull from the private registry instead of the docker hub

Answer (score 0):

> We need to pull all our base images form a private docker registry. Is pulling the image from docker hub and pushing it to the private registry the only option to achieve the above requirement.

You need to use [`docker login`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) to log into your private registry before you execute docker pull\push commands

> Also how to pass credentials of my private registry and tell my Dockerfile to pull from the private registry instead of the docker hub

The registry's address is to be specified in the image tag name as [exampled here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli):

```
docker tag nginx myregistry.azurecr.io/samples/nginx
```